# Visual Studio 2010 Editor stops working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

My MSVisualStudio was working fine and suddenly it's text editor stops accepting user input. I closed my application and it says:

`Microsoft Visual Studio has detected that an operation is blocking user input. This can be caused by an active modal dialog or task that needs to block user interaction. Would you like to shut down anyway?`

[image]

How to solve this Problem. Can anyone help me please. I also run my application as administrator and  it not allows me to access my application by saying that application is in used by other program.

Comment: There are some things you can try at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce6868ac-de2e-443b-ab11-e5cc7464c546/operation-is-blocking-user-input

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't help me :(

Comment: Well, can you Repair it under the Control Panel?

Comment: no i haven't try this

Comment: The WPF designer is quite a tragedy.  Don't expect smooth sailing when you see "An Unhandled Exception has occurred".  This is otherwise a sign of misbehaving add-ins.

Comment: Yes @HansPassant so any alternative?

Answer (score 8):

Do you have Resharper? I had the same exact issue with Resharper installed but suspended because my license was expired. I uninstalled it and everything works fine now.

Comment: I also have ReSharper. Disabling it did not fix the issue. Which is interesting, it mostly happens on the first start of VS for the given day and not related to the complexity of work I do with it, also not related to WPF designer. Otherwise the same issue.